# Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: Data provider internal error(-3000) [System.String]

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I am getting below error when code deployed on the server - 
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: Data provider internal error(-3000) [System.String]

I am using Oracle client 12c and .Net V 4.5.1

Stack trace for detail -

[OracleException (0x80004005): Data provider internal error(-3000) [System.String]]
   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck, Int32 isRecoverable) +1383
   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, Object src) +49
   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open() +5246
   CSG.LCD.PAT.SystemFramework.DataManagement.DbHelper.PrepareCommandObject(IDbCommand cmd) +183
   CSG.LCD.PAT.SystemFramework.DataManagement.DbHelper.ExecuteDataSet(String sql, CommandType commType, ParameterCollection parameters, String[] tableName) +174
   CSG.LCD.PAT.SystemFramework.DataManagement.DbHelper.ExecuteForDataSet(String sql, CommandType commType, ParameterCollection parameters, String[] tableName) +57
   CSG.LCD.PAT.SystemFramework.DataManagement.DbHelper.ExecuteForDataSet(String sql, CommandType commType, ParameterCollection parameters) +56
   CSG.LCD.PAT.DAL.DataAdministration.EntitlementDAL.GetAccessCheck(String pID, String& dualHubAccess, String& swissFlag) in G:\D\N\CSG.LCD.PAT.DAL\DataAdministration\EntitlementDAL.cs:1503
   CSG.LCD.PAT.BusinessManager.DataAdministration.EntitlementManager.GetAccessCheck(String pID, String& dualHubAccess, String& swissFlag) in G:\D\N\CSG.LCD.PAT.BusinessManager\DataAdministration\EntitlementManager.cs:358
   CSG.LCD.PAT.WEB.UtilityHelper.GetAccessCheck(String pID, String provider, String role, String& dualHubAccess, String& swissAccess) in G:\D\N\CSG.LCD.PAT.WEB\Utility\UtilityHelper.cs:2256
   CSG.LCD.PAT.WEB.Global.Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) in G:\D\N\CSG.LCD.PAT.WEB\Global.asax.cs:26
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.RaiseOnStart(EventArgs e) +9771167
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.CompleteAcquireState() +155
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.BeginAcquireState(Object source, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +1095
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +285
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Comment: Is Oracle installed on the server? If so, make sure there is not a version mismatch between what is installed and what assembly your code is using. This has happened to me before when we had a different version of Oracle.DataAccess registered to the GAC on the production server vs the dll included in my project.

Comment: You didn't actually ask a question; you just made a problem statement. The code that reproduces the error might be helpful

Comment: on server there are both versions installed 32 bit and 64 bit

Comment: You need to compare the dll version